# Hey, How do I write rules for a Rock, Paper, Scissor that I've been writing with tkinter in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, if-statement, tkinter, global-variables

So, I've been trying to write a Rock, paper and scissor game with tkinter to learn python. And I have made the GUI and the bot displays different moves after each the button click. However, the changing buttons don't affect the scoreboard. I need help writing the rules since I'm new at coding.
Please take a look at the code.

```
# pictures on buttons
photo1 = PhotoImage(file=r"E:\ROCK.png")
photoimage = photo1.subsample(9, 9)
photo2 = PhotoImage(file=r"E:\download.png")
photoimage1 = photo2.subsample(4, 4)
photo3 = PhotoImage(file=r"E:\SCISSOR.png")
photoimage2 = photo3.subsample(4, 4)

#bot's move

global list
global choice
list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
choice = random.choice(list) 

global move
global imgbot
global bmove
bmove = int(choice)

#function of buttons

#function of Rock
def click():
    global move, imgbot, choice, i
    i = 1
    move = 1


    if choice == 1:
        imgbot = photoimage

    if choice == 2:
        imgbot = photoimage1

    if choice == 3:
        imgbot = photoimage2
    if move == 1 or move == 2 or move == 3:
        choice = random.choice(list)
        botmove.config(image=imgbot)


#function of paper
def click1():
    global move, imgbot, choice, i
    i = 2
    move = 2
    if choice == 1:
        imgbot = photoimage

    if choice == 2:
        imgbot = photoimage1

    if choice == 3:
        imgbot = photoimage2
    if move == 1 or move == 2 or move == 3:
        botmove.config(image=imgbot)
        choice = random.choice(list)

#function of scissor
def click2():
    global move, imgbot, choice, i
    i = 3
    move = 3
    if choice == 1:
        imgbot = photoimage

    if choice == 2:
        imgbot = photoimage1

    if choice == 3:
        imgbot = photoimage2
    if move == 1 or move == 2 or move == 3:
        botmove.config(image=imgbot)
        choice = random.choice(list)

 # components

#Score board
scorep = 0
scoreb = 0
Scoreboard = Label(window, text=str("BOT- ") + str(scoreb) + str(":") + str(scorep) + str(" -YOU "))

#other components
button2 = Button(window, text="Close Game", command=close, padx=20)
botmove = Button(window, padx=20, pady=20, image=photoimage3)
prock = Button(window, image=photoimage, command=click)
ppaper = Button(window, image=photoimage1, command=click1)
pscissor = Button(window, image=photoimage2, command=click2)
```

I want to be able to continuously update the score as they win or lose and display "WIN", "LOSE" or "DRAW", I can do the positioning myself. I defined move as an integer so that I could write "if move-bmove = something then display win, or lose or draw". There is a global variable "i" because I was playing around with other ways of doing this but they failed so you can ignore "i". I did not include the whole code, only the important bits and necessary context.

I hope you understand my problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: First of all saying `global` in the main block (here, outside of functions) is totally useless, and can be removed

Comment: Do not use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

See the comments inline

```
import random

alternatives = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors')

# we can emulate a 3x3 table with a nested dictionary
# the first layer is the player choice, the second is the result according to the bot choice
rules = {
    'rock': # if player chooses rock
        {'rock': 'draw', 'paper': 'loose', 'scissors': 'win'}, # results according to bot choice
    'paper': {'rock': 'win', 'paper': 'draw', 'scissors': 'loose'},
    'scissors': {'rock': 'loose', 'paper': 'win', 'scissors': 'draw'}
}

# photos = { # whenever you have a collection objects of the same type (e.g. PhotoImage instances)
    # # it is a good idea to make a dictionary so you can dinamically access each item
    # key: PhotoImage(file=f'E:\\{key.upper()}.png') 
    # for key in alternatives
    # # this is called a 'dictionary comprehension' or 'dict-comprehension'
# }

# later you can get each photo with
# photos[player_move] # returns the PhotoImage object



score = [0, 0] # player, bot

# then you can create a single function to update the score, regardless of the choice
# and call it when a player makes a move
def update_score(player_choice):
    ''' keep in mind
    score: list of [player, bot] integer scores
    player_choice: string with the player's choice, provided by the button click
    '''
    
    bot_choice = random.choice(alternatives)
    
    # `score` and `result` are mutable objects
    # therefore they are accessible in main and all its dependant namespaces
    # i.e. we can inspect `rules` and modify `score`
    # without calling `global` / `nonlocal` inside the function
    result = rules[player_choice][bot_choice]
    if result == 'win':
        score[0] += 1
        out = 'lucky dog!'
    elif result == 'loose':
        score[1] += 1
        out = 'what a looser...'
    else:
        out = 'we live to fight another day'
    
    # notice we already updated score, so we don't need a return line
    print(bot_choice, player_choice, '::', out)
```

Test it with

```
for player_choice in random.choices(population=alternatives, weights=(1, 1, 1), k=20):
    update_score(player_choice)
    
# score_text = f'BOT {str(score[1])} : {str(score[0])} YOU'
score_text = (
    'BOT ' + 
    ' : '.join( # takes a sequence of strings and joins them into a single string
        list(map(str, score[::-1])) # iterates `score` backwards and applies string to each value
        ) +
    ' YOU'
)
print(score_text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I tried to integrate into my code, no errors but it doesn't work exactly. I will keep working to put it in my code properly.

Comment: You're welcome, it was fun... consider selecting as accepted answer and upvoting